# python pandas missing required dependencies 'numpy' in visual studio

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, anaconda

I have anaconda3 installed on my Windows 10 machine.
I want to get the python script to run and return the results to C#.
So here is my code in C#:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();

start.FileName = @"C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Cotinum\anaconda3\python.exe";
start.Arguments = string.Format("{0}", @"C:\test.py", "test");

start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
{
    string foo = reader.ReadToEnd();
    TxtResultOutput.Text += foo;
}
```

The python code

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

def test_func(f_name):
    a = pd.read_excel(f_name)
    return a
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    f_name = sys.argv[1]
test_func(f_name)
```

When I run C# code, in the output window of Visual Studio. It shows the error:

> File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-package\pandas__init__.py", line 19,
>
> in module
>
> "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
>
> ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

However I don't believe I missed it because I can run the script from anaconda3 prompt window. It must be that somehow the PATH can't found in Visual Studio/ C# environment.

Comment: _It must be that somehow the PATH can't found in Visual Studio/ C# environment._ I'm not familiar with Visual Studio (Code?), is there any way to set the interpreter/environment in the settings?

Comment: No, I don't think so. But I am thinking is that possible setting PATH in C# code?